# Cannot set property "color" of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, undefined

I'm trying to make a simple candyCrush-like game but I keep getting this error and don't know what to do.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined
>       at testForClick (numbercrunch2.html:50)
>       at update (numbercrunch2.html:62)

To recreate the error just put some numbers into the text boxes, hit the starting button and click on a random tile.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var tilesX = 0,
  tilesY = 0,
  tilesWidthX, tilesWidthY, space = 3;
var numb = [];

var mousepos = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  click = false;

function init(rows, cols) {
  tilesWidthX = (canvas.height - rows * 3) / rows;
  tilesWidthY = (canvas.height - cols * 3) / cols;
  tilesX = rows;
  tilesY = cols;

  for (var i = 0; i < tilesX; i++) {
    numb[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < tilesY; j++) {
      numb[i][j] = {
        val: 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 6),
        color: "grey"
      };

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = numb[i][j].color;
      ctx.fillRect(space + i * (tilesWidthY + space), space + j * (tilesWidthX + space), tilesWidthY, tilesWidthX);
      ctx.closePath();

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.fillStyle = "white";
      ctx.font = "20px Arial";
      ctx.fillText(numb[i][j].val, 15 + i * (tilesWidthY + space), 30 + j * (tilesWidthY + space), 50);
      ctx.closePath();
    }
  }
}

function testForClick(x, y) {
  if (space + x * (tilesWidthX + space) <= mousepos.x && space + y * (tilesWidthY + space) <= mousepos.y && (x + 1) * (tilesWidthX + space) >= mousepos.x && (y + 1) * (tilesWidthY + space) >= mousepos.y) {
    numb[x][y].color = "green"; //line 50
  }
}

function drawTile(x, y) {

}

function update() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    numb[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      testForClick(i, j);
      drawTile(i, j);
    }
  }
}
setInterval(update, 300);

function mouseposition(e) {

}
document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  mousepos.x = e.clientX;
  mousepos.y = e.clientY;
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="600"></canvas>
<form name="formname">
  Rows: <input type="text" name="rows"> Columns: <input type="text" name="columns">
  <input type="button" value="Start" onClick="init(this.form.rows.value, this.form.columns.value)">
</form>
<div id="t"></div>
```

Comment: maybe you target a tile out of bounce ? like.. if you have a scare 2x2... make sure you dont target a scare x position 3.

Comment: The numb[x][y] does not refer to a valid element. Find out why. We can't really duplicate the problem ourselves, since we don't know the HTML or the numbers that are being used to call testForClick().

Comment: I made a snippet of your JavaScript code, now please add a small bit of HTML and any CSS that demonstrates the issue with as little markup as possible!

Comment: What are you expecting? are you supposed to change the color after a single click on a tile based on the calculated coords?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? can you elaborate on the functionality of the game?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run `update()` you literally update your `numb` variable by replacing the previous object for an empty `Array object` thus when calling `testForClick()` it has no object in it throwing the `error`.

```
function update() {
    for (var i = 0;i < 9;i++) {
        numb[i] = [];
        for ( var j = 0;j < 9;j++) {
            testForClick(i,j);
            drawTile(i,j);
        }
    }
} setInterval(update,300);
```

Should be:

```
function update()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            testForClick(i, j);
            drawTile(i, j);
        }
    }
};
```

I created a snippet showing how commenting (or removing) the `numb[i] = [];` line from `update()` will make it work.

I updated your script:

```
// Also, I renamed your 'c' var to 'canvas' because in your init() you are calling it canvas and not 'c'.
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var tilesX = 0, tilesY = 0, tilesWidthX, tilesWidthY, space = 3;
var numb = [];

var mousepos = {x: 0, y: 0}, click = false;

function init(rows, cols)
{
    tilesWidthX = (canvas.height - rows * 3) / rows;
    tilesWidthY = (canvas.height - cols * 3) / cols;
    tilesX = rows;
    tilesY = cols;

    for (var i = 0; i < tilesX; i++)
    {
        numb[i] = [];

        for (var j = 0; j < tilesY; j++)
        {
            numb[i][j] = {
                val: 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 6),
                color: 'grey'
            };

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = numb[i][j].color;
            ctx.fillRect(space + i * (tilesWidthY + space), space + j * (tilesWidthX + space), tilesWidthY, tilesWidthX);
            ctx.closePath();

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
            ctx.font = '20px Arial';
            ctx.fillText(numb[i][j].val, 15 + i * (tilesWidthY + space), 30 + j * (tilesWidthY + space), 50);
            ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
}

function testForClick(x, y)
{
    // Now your 'numb' variable hasn't been changed.
    console.log('testForClick', numb);

    if (space + x * (tilesWidthX + space) <= mousepos.x && space + y * (tilesWidthY + space) <= mousepos.y && (x+1) * (tilesWidthX + space) >= mousepos.x && (y+1) * (tilesWidthY + space) >= mousepos.y)
    {
        numb[x][y].color = 'green'; //line 50
    }
}

function drawTile(x, y)
{
}

function update()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        // Every time you update you replace your object with 'val' and 'color' for an empty array.
        // that is the reason why every time you call testForClick you have no object in it.
        // Just comment/delete this line so your object never disappears.
        // numb[i] = [];

        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            testForClick(i, j);
            drawTile(i, j);
        }
    }
};

// Changed the interval because I didn't have enough time to enter the rows and columns.
setInterval(update, 5000);

function mouseposition(e)
{
}

document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    mousepos.x = e.clientX;
    mousepos.y = e.clientY;
}, false);
```

SNIPPET:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var tilesX = 0, tilesY = 0, tilesWidthX, tilesWidthY, space = 3;
var numb = [];

var mousepos = {x: 0, y: 0}, click = false;

function init(rows, cols)
{
 tilesWidthX = (canvas.height - rows * 3) / rows;
 tilesWidthY = (canvas.height - cols * 3) / cols;
 tilesX = rows;
 tilesY = cols;

 for (var i = 0; i < tilesX; i++)
 {
  numb[i] = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < tilesY; j++)
  {
   numb[i][j] = {
    val: 1 + Math.round(Math.random() * 6),
    color: 'grey'
   };

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.fillStyle = numb[i][j].color;
   ctx.fillRect(space + i * (tilesWidthY + space), space + j * (tilesWidthX + space), tilesWidthY, tilesWidthX);
   ctx.closePath();

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
   ctx.font = '20px Arial';
   ctx.fillText(numb[i][j].val, 15 + i * (tilesWidthY + space), 30 + j * (tilesWidthY + space), 50);
   ctx.closePath();
  }
 }
}

function testForClick(x, y)
{
 // Now your 'numb' variable hasn't been changed.
 console.log('testForClick', numb);

 if (space + x * (tilesWidthX + space) <= mousepos.x && space + y * (tilesWidthY + space) <= mousepos.y && (x+1) * (tilesWidthX + space) >= mousepos.x && (y+1) * (tilesWidthY + space) >= mousepos.y)
 {
  numb[x][y].color = 'green'; //line 50
 }
}

function drawTile(x, y)
{
}

function update()
{
 for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
 {
  for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++)
  {
   testForClick(i, j);
   drawTile(i, j);
  }
 }
};

setInterval(update, 5000);

function mouseposition(e)
{
}

document.getElementById('canvas').addEventListener('click', function(e){
 mousepos.x = e.clientX;
 mousepos.y = e.clientY;
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>numbercrunch 2</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   canvas {
    border: 2px solid black;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <canvas id="canvas" height="600" width="600"></canvas>
 <form name="formname">
  Rows: <input type="text" name="rows">
  Columns: <input type="text" name="columns">
  <input type="button" value="Start" onClick="init(this.form.rows.value, this.form.columns.value)">
 </form>
 <div id="t"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```